# Connect With FTP Server From Android Programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am try to create ftp client for android but i didn't connect with server  https://www.drivehq.com/ is my host for this application.and library is "org.apache.commons.net_2.0.0.v200905272248 (1).jar"

below is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
ftpConnect("www.drivehq.com","uname","password",21);
}
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password,int port) {
try {
mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
mFTPClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(host));
if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
//boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
tv.setText("Connected");
//return true;//status;
}
tv.setText("not Connected");
} catch (Exception e) {
tv.setText(""+e);
}
return false;
}
```

Its just show me blank screen nothing in TextView. i also try to provide host name like https://www.drivehq.com/ and www.drivehq.com/ and http://www.drivehq.com/
And when i connect with ftp server so how can i show its folder etc means using webview?

Thanks.

Comment: http is not ftp. Are you sure there is an ftp server there ?

Comment: you can visit it i not have experience please guide me about it